# Pattern-mixture models

Tags: binomial-distribution, missing-data, joint-distribution, mathematical-statistics, pattern-mixture

I am currently looking at pattern-mixture models but I don't seem to understand them and I wonder whether someone could help.

I can see the model comes from the factorisation $  f(y,r;\phi, \theta)=f(y|r;\phi)f(r;\theta) $ where y is the data, r the missingness and $\phi$, $\theta$ parameters; and I'm looking at the simplest example to see how it works: $ y_i $ is observed $i=1,...,m$ and missing $i=m+1,...,n$ and missingness comes from a bernoulli distribution with parameter $\pi$. Following the factorisation to obtain the joint distribution I get this:

$$  f(y_i,r_i;\phi,\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{m}f(y_i|R_i=1;\phi)P[R_i=1]$$

and

$$\eqalign{&\prod_{i=m+1}^{n}f(y_i|R_i=0;\phi)P[R_i=0] \\&= \pi^m(1-\pi)^{n -m}\prod_{i=1}^{m}f(y_i|R_i=1;\phi)\prod_{i=m+1}^{n}f(y_i|R_i=0;\phi)}$$

but I don't observe any values for $ y_i $ from $i=m+1,...,n$, so I just ignore the part where $R_i=0$? It seems to me that I'm doing something wrong but I can't see what it is.

Any suggestions?